# What is the best way for distributed processes to communicate asynchronously?

Tags: c++, sockets, messaging

I'm developing an application in which distributed components talk to one another over a network, in an asynchronous, pub/sub kind of way.

For this, I like the idea of sending XML over sockets - it's asynchronous, I don't need a server of any kind, and it can work locally or over a network. I would have to roll my own pub/sub mechanism, which probably won't be too onerous - I could use the IP address as the id of the subscriber. The implementation language will be C++. I've used this method before with good results. But, I wonder if there is a better way? Any advice welcome.

Edit: I haven't made a decision yet, but I'm interested in cparcode's comment on protobuf:

"I never understood the popularity of using XML for network comms. Any way, I realize that the protocol is only part of your problem but on that subject, there's Google's protobuf too: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/ – caparcode (Mar 11 at 1:01)"

Comment: Ummm ... sockets natively asynch? maybe in a parallel universe?

Comment: all modern socket libraries have asynch APIs

Comment: Things to watch out for:  XML parsing performance, persistent socket memory overhead, etc.   But, like others have said, if you've done it in the past, then you can do it again.  It would be nice to detail your other requirements:  How many machines in the network?  Are there perf requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using XML it might be best to use an existing message passing framework. Have a look at [libt2n](http://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libt2n/index.php) or [d-bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus)

But it you have used your own socket implementation in the past with good results i don't see a reason why you should change. If it ain't broke don't fix it :)

Comment: I never understood the popularity of using XML for network comms. Any way, I realize that the protocol is only part of your problem but on that subject, there's Google's protobuf too: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Comment: +1 on protobuf.  far more compact than any text-based format, and an easy to use API for C++, Java and Python ensures interoperability.

Comment: Dbus is good if the tasks will always be on the same machine.  I believe you can make it travel across IP to other machines with a little work but it's not really meant for that use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just straight sockets, you might [consider a solution like AMQP](http://www.amqp.org).

When you're talking about using socket connections for a pub/sub interface, that usually means point-to-point communication, which isn't always a scalable solution.  AMQP really addresses this sort of pub/sub problem.  It's free, it's open-source, and it works.

Given that they've already solved the pub/sub problem, you might want to leverage off their work instead of doing it yourself.

I recommend [OpenAMQ.](http://www.openamq.org)

That being said, it really depends on what sort of environment you're working in.  AMQP requires an AMQP broker (an application responsible for routing messages) to be running somewhere in the system.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/). It's a [JMS](http://java.sun.com/products/jms/) provider and also has bindings in lots of other languages, works on several transports, and has a selection of protocols that it uses for its messages.

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ is also an AMQP broker, that supports other protocols like XMPP, HTTP, STOMP, SMTP as well, using adaptors.

Answer (score 0):

Especially if you have done it before, and it still meets your needs, stick with it.

Comment: but now that he knows how to do it, he's thinking of improving it.

Answer (score 0):

How about embedding a web server in your app? [EasyHTTPD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ehttpd/) is open source, C++, and pretty simple to use. The asynchronous part is easy enough. You either spin up a new thread on the sender or the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for XML, and cross-platform to boot, you may consider an XML-RPC mechanism like SOAP (I've used gSoap for communication between a C server on linux with a C++ client on win32, and it worked fine once you figure it all out).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not heavily inclined towards XML and you want something simple and efficient then consider looking at [YAMI](http://www.msobczak.com/prog/yami/) library. It is rather simple to use and the given link contains enough documentation, rationale and examples to get started.